# Проблема с доступом в папку с httaccess под Yii2

Tags: yii2, .htaccess

Здравствуйте.Возникла проблема с `.htaccess`.

В корневой директории есть директория под названием "dtf". И проблема в том, когда я перехожу по следующем пути `http://site.name/dtf/ymi` - мне отображается главная страница самого сайта(которая до этого была `frontend/web/site/index`.

Содержимое .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(backend/web|admin)
RewriteRule !^frontend/web /frontend/web%{REQUEST_URI} [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin(.*) /backend/web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /backend/web/index.php [L]
```

Как решить проблему данного рода? Спасибо.

Comment: Так и не понятно в чем заключается проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить 3-ей строкой **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(dtf)**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(backend/web|admin)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(dtf)
RewriteRule !^frontend/web /frontend/web%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

*via xmoonlight*

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите чтобы директория была доступна в браузере, переместите директорию `dtf` в директорию `frontend/web`

Comment: Увы, пробовал - возвращало Forbidden.